# Multi-threaded queue consumer in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, queue

I'm writing an image processing system in PHP that should spawn 3-5 workers that will monitor a location / queue for new images, and then process them (using locking so there's no race conditions).

The tricky part is I want to include it for generic CMS platforms. For that reason I can't assume that any particular extensions are enabled, since often it will be on shared hosting.

Is it possible to write a multi-threaded image processor that works with a locking queue without being sure that (for example) PHP's `semaphore` or `pcntl` are available? I haven't been able to come up with anything, but I'm hoping there's a way to work this in PHP using native PHP functions rather than having to install PEAR items or reconfigure PHP.

I could install items via Composer-- just not core PHP libs.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Can you write lock files to disk?

Comment: I almost think you would get a better answer over at programmers.stackexchange.com.  Here is their guidelines: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @GuySchalnat when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Yes, you are right.  I have to ask them to delete this question and then post it there.  I also flagged it for moving, but if the user does that, it helps reduce the workload for the monitors.

Comment: @ParrisVarney-- yes, I could write lock files